# If I cancel my Google+ account, will I lose my Google OpenID functionality?

Tags: openid, google-plus

I wanted to close my Google+ account, but when I went to do so, one of the items in the “Read this before proceeding” section mentions:

> - You won't be able to use the "Sign in with Google" button to log in to third-party apps.

I assume they mean OpenID, but I’m not sure.

Comment: I would assume so.

Comment: There should be two options: closing your Google+ account and deleting your Google account entirely. Those aren't related AFAIK. Unless they changed that recently.

Answer (score 1):

I once closed or disabled my Google+ and next time I wanted to log in to Stackexchange I got a weird message about missing Google+ and it wanted me to activate it again.

So if you close your Google+ you will probably not be allowed to use OpenID until you activate it again.

At least that's what happened to me. This was a while ago so Google might have changed something since then.